# Using asynchronous function in conditional in nodejs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to make an xp leaderboard for my discord bot. It works perfectly except it shows users that aren't in the server, but in a different one. I figured out how to check if the person is in the server, but it returns a promise. The on message function is synchronous. Is there any way I can await the async function I made to return if the user is in the server? Code below:

Async function :

```
async function validUser(message, i) {
    valid = await message.guild.members.fetch(i).then(member => {
        console.log(member)
        return true
    }).catch(err => {
        return false
    })
    console.log(valid)
    return valid
}
```

Leaderboard code:

```
                if (typeof i.split('channel')[1] === 'undefined' && await validUser(message, i)) {
                    if (typeof xpvals[i][2] != 'undefined') {
                        dudename = xpvals[i][2]
                        dudexp = xpvals[i][0]
                        dudefull = [dudename, dudexp]
                ...
```

Comment: I think your code is wrong. You don't need to use **then** when await is used. Leaderboard code is synchronous?

Comment: @JRichardsz You don't need to but you can. It's designed to work that way since `.then()` are chainable and always return a Promise. When you do that the `await` waits for the promise returned by the last `.then()` in the chain, not the function you call. So in the code above the `await` keyword is operating on `.then()`, not on `.fetch()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discord.js lets you have a synchronous and asynchronous form of the on message at the same time. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is running the variable valid as true even if fetch doesn't find the member.
Try:

```
valid = await message.guild.members.fetch(i).then(member => {
    console.log(member)
    if(member) return true
    else return false
})
```

Comment: Nice catch. An empty result is usually **NOT** an error so `catch()` will not catch it

Comment: @slebetman I believe it throws 404 not found if the member isn't found

Comment: It all works but I need to wait for the result before the leaderboard is calculated.